# Guest Access on a Windows Home Network

Tags: networking

I am trying to set up a guest network from a remote building at my home.
The network in the main house has access to all devices including my Synology NAS via an Asus AX6000 RT-AX88U router.
Access to the internet is via a Draytek Vigor 130 Modem.
There is a CAT 6 cable from the remote building currently connected to the Asus router.
I have set up an old Netgear D6200 Router as a Wireless Access Point in the remote building.

This all works fine except that I want to restrict access in the remote building to the internet only to keep my home network private.

I have tried setting up a Guest Network on the Netgear router but this does not work as the router needs access back to the Asus router over the home network.

I have also tried linking the Asus router and the Netgear router to a switch, then connecting the switch to the modem.
This did not work as the Netgear router has a built in modem which it seems cannot be disabled.

I have looked at the possibility of setting up a subnetwork but have very little knowledge on this subject.
Although there is a lot of stuff on the internet about the theory of subnetworks, I have not found anything on the practicalities.

Is it possible to set up one network on the Asus and a different one on the Netgear, for example, then assign different access right to each device?

I do have an old Draytek Vigor 2830 which could be pressed into service if needs be as this seems to have the option of subnets built in.

Below is the schematic of my network.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Network diagram]

Following changes suggested by harrymc, I show a revised schematic.

[image]

On further investigation I have discovered that harrymc's suggestion did, in fact, solve the problem and my home network is not accessible from the Netgear network.

"*If you enable the Netgear as DHCP server with IP addresses that are not in the Asus network, the guests will effectively be isolated in their own sub-network.*"

What was misleading me was the fact that I had 2 drives mapped from my Synology DiskStation and these were still accessible. I am not sure why this is.

Once I disconnected the mapped drives, they could not be reconnected. Many thanks to harrymc for solving my problem and apologies for my misunderstandings.

Comment: Can anyone offer an explanation as to why the mapped drives still appear when I am connected to the alternative network on the Netgear router?

Answer (score 1):

The
[RT-AX88U manual](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking-IoT-Servers/WiFi-Routers/ASUS-Gaming-Routers/RT-AX88U/HelpDesk_Manual/)
describes the process in section 3.2, page 26, section
"Creating a Guest Network":

> The Guest Network provides temporary visitors with Internet
> connectivity via access to separate SSIDs or networks without
> providing access to your private network.
>
> To create a guest network:
>
> 1. From the navigation panel, go to General > Guest Network.
> 2. On the Guest Network screen, select 2.4Ghz or SGhz frequency band for the guest network that you want to create.
> 3. Click Enable.
> 4. To conf‌igure additional options, click Modify.
> 5. Click Yes on the Enable Guest Network screen.
> 6. Assign a wireless name for your temporary network on the Network Name (SSID) f‌ield.
> 7. Select an Authentication Method.
> 8. Select an Encryption method.
> 9. Specify the Access time or choose Limitless.
> 10. Select Disable or Enable on the Access Intranet item.
> 11. When done, click Apply.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I don't think this will give me what I need. Guests will be accessing the network via wi-fi on the Netgear router. The remote building they will be staying in is too far away from the Asus router to connect to this wirelessly. Perhaps there is a way to access the guest network via one of the RJ45 inputs but I am not aware that this is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your schema. Idea: If you enable the Netgear as DHCP server with IP addresses that are not in the Asus network, the guests will effectively be isolated in their own sub-network. Define the Asus network as weirdly as possible, example `192.168.99.xxx`. Put also a very complex password on the Netgear. Weakness:  If the guests can reset their router, they will undo everything that you did. Solution: Enable on the Asus MAC filters to allow only your devices, to protect against that.

Comment: Thanks for your new comment. I have tried your suggestions but without success. I have not changed the addresses on the Asus as I assume that you intended to say "Define the NETGEAR network …" rather than "Define the ASUS network …". Please let me know if my assumption is incorrect. I have 1 standard and 1 guest network (with local access turned off) on the Netgear router. Both Netgear networks have internet access but both also have local network access. I have an new schematic of my network but am not sure how to upload it. Please will you let me know if I have misunderstood anything.

Comment: If the network schema is correct, it can't not succeed. Please edit your post with a correct schema and what exactly you have done that didn't work.

Comment: I am sure I must have missed something. I tried connecting the Netgear LAN port to the Asus LAN port as well. I also tried connecting the Netgear through a switch rather than direct to the Asus router. The arrangement shown in the new schematic does give me a distinct network on the Netgear router but I can still access the local network.

Comment: Have you set the Netgear to be a DHCP server?

Comment: Yes, I have and devices connected to the Netgear network are being assigned IP addresses in the range of 192.168.99.xx. If I analyse the Asus network, the Netgear router appears as a device in the range of 192.168.50.xx. Would you expect that? Do you agree with the way I have connected the 2 routers? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: The Netgear has two IPs in the two directions : internal on its local created sub-network and external on the network of the Asus. This is normal and expected.

Comment: @WightRob MAC filters are not an effective security policy since they can be spoofed with no technical expertise.